# TwilioClient IOS SDK version 1.2.11 on iOS10

Tags: ios, twilio, voip, ios10

TwilioClient IOS SDK version 1.2.11 seems not working on iOS10, because **Legacy VoIP background mode is deprecated and no longer supported**. Is it right? If it is true, where should we go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You'll want to check out the newly released [Twilio Programmable Voice SDK for iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk). It supports Apple's VoIP Services Push Notifications now. Check out the [release blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/beta-programmable-voice-sdk-for-ios-with-support-for-voip-services-push-notifications.html) and the [quickstart project](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/ios/getting-started).

Comment: Working on the new SDK now.  New SDK need the API Key,  but sub-account can not use master account's API Key, generated access token using sub-account sid and master account API key failed on VoiceClient.sharedInstance().register.

Comment: Have you tried signing in to the Twilio console as the subaccount and creating an API Key and secret there? You can create API Keys here: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/dev-tools/api-keys

Comment: But Twilio Programmable Voice SDK is still in beta mode. Will this be good to use it now?

Comment: The [limitations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk) on the beta are: "Twilio Programmable Voice SDK is currently available as a Public Beta release. Some features are not yet implemented, and others will change before the product is generally available." If you want to use the updated notifications you do need to try the beta though.